# Probability density of $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ when $(X,Y)$ is distributed in a disk

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function

I am struggling with the following question:

- Let $\left(X, Y\right)$ be a pair of random variables with joint density function $\mathrm{g}\left(x,y\right) = \frac{1}{2}xy$ if $\left(x,y\right)\in D$, $0$ else. Here, $D$ denotes the first quarter of the disk of radius $2$ centered at $\left(0,0\right)$.
- First the problem asks if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This is easy, we can simply integrate.

My issue is with the second question:

- Find the density of the random variable $R = \,\sqrt{\, X^{2} + Y^{2}\, }\,$ and then that of $R^{2}$.

I imagine this is related to a change of variables as it looks like polar coordinates but I don't understand what I am supposed to do here.

Comment: Find CDF of $R$ and $R^2$. Then afterwards you can find PDF by differentiating.

Comment: Also what do you mean when you say "we can simply integrate" to determine if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: I don't understand how to determine the CDF here, because it's one variable $R$ but its determined by two other variables. This is partly why I am asking this question. As for integration, you can compute the marginal densities via integration and then multiply them to check whether they're equal to the joint density. If that's true, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand what you're saying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The cumulative distribution function of $\ R\ $ is given by
\begin{align}
P(R\le \rho)&=\iint_{D\cap \cal{D}_\rho}\frac{xy}{2}dxdy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\rho\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}r^3\cos\theta\sin\theta\, d\theta dr\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ \cal{D}_\rho=\left\{(x,y)\left|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le \rho\right.\right\}\ $, and its density function can be obtained by differentiating this. And $\ P(R^2\le r)=$$P\left(R\le \sqrt{r}\right)\ $.

Comment: Ah I see, for some reason I got that integral but I wrote 2 instead of $\rho$ because I thought integrating over a disk of radius 2 would induce a 2 in the integral. The only thing I don't understand is why there is an $r$ and a $\rho$. Shouldn't we integrate over $D \cap \mathcal{D}_\rho$?

Comment: Yes, you're right about the $\ \rho\ $. I originally used the symbol "$r$" for the variable in the distribution function and neglected to change the subscript in the first $\ \cal{D_r}\ $ when I replaced that symbol with "$\rho$". I have now corrected it.  And you will have an upper limit of $2$ in the integral if $\ \rho>2\ $.  My answer is only valid for $\ 0\le\rho\le2\ $.

Comment: Thanks I understand now! So what happens exactly if $\rho$ is greater than 2? Do I have to split the CDF in two functions depending on $\rho$?

Comment: Three cases.  It's value is $0$ when $\ \rho<0\ $, $1$ when $\ \rho>2\ $ and is given by the integral in my answer when $\ 0\le\rho\le2\ $.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought then, thanks for clearing it up!